# How to convert a part of string to lowercase in c#

Tags: c#, string, lowercase

I have a string like this **LUXOR** and I want to convert other letters to lowercase except first letter or the string.that meant, I want this string **Luxor** from above string. I can convert full string to upper or lower by using `ToUpper` or `ToLower`.but how can I do this.hope your help with this.thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can make use of [`TextInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.globalization.textinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) class that Defines text properties and behaviors, such as casing, that is specific to a writing system.

```
 string inString = "LUXOR".ToLower();
 TextInfo cultInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).TextInfo;
 string output = cultInfo.ToTitleCase(inString);
```

> This snippet will give you `Luxor` in the variable `output`. this can
>   also be used to capitalize Each Words First Letter

Another option is using .SubString, for this particular scenario of having a single word input:

```
string inString = "LUXOR"
string outString = inString.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + inString.Substring(1).ToLower();
```

Comment: A little bit of context/explanation might be nice! +1 for the script/language-independent solution, though.

Comment: Your original answer will actually NOT work for **ALL UPPERCASE** texts, because these are exempt from the conversion ; they are seen as abbreviations! `"this is FBI calling"` will render `"This Is FBI Calling"`. Your updated answer is a bit too complex for the simple task requested.

Comment: Also, please don't link the `TextInfo` word to some blog. Link to MSDN directly.

Comment: @AndersTornblad: thanks for the valuable point, I have updated the answer with `string inString = "LUXOR".ToLower();` and also corrected the link

Comment: nice one.I like for second method. thank your very much

Comment: @Graham'anu' -  Beware that in the second one, you are creating 4 extra strings (Substring x 2) and (ToLower x 2)

Answer (score 1):

Try This,

```
        string inString = "LUXOR";
        string output = inString.Substring(0, 1) + inString.Substring(1).ToLower();

        string inString2 = "HI HOW ARE YOU";
        string[] finalstring = inString2.Split(' ');

        string output2 = string.Empty;
        foreach (var item in finalstring)
        {
            if (output2 == "")
            {
                output2 = (item.ToUpper().Substring(0, 1) + item.ToLower().Substring(1));
            }
            else
            {
                output2 += " " + (item.ToUpper().Substring(0, 1) + item.ToLower().Substring(1));
            }

        }
```